How to Properly use Argument Captor on a Spied super class method using Mockito and JDK11
I have a class A:
class A extends X {

    public String execute(Input input) {
      // Do something here
    }

}

Then I have class B:
class B extends A {

    public String execute(Input input) {
        newInput = updateInput(input); // adds name in the end
        super.execute(newInput);
    }

}

I'm trying to capture the input that is being sent to super.execute() using the following code in my tests:
expectedInput = "hello anirudh"

input = "hello"

B object = new B();

B spyB = spy(object);

ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = forClass(Input.class);

doReturn(null).when((A) spyB).execute(captor.capture());

spyB.execute(input);

capturedArg = captor.getvalue();

I've also tried
verify((A) spyB).execute(
    argThat(argument -> {
        return argument.equals(expectedInput);
    }));

Using the above code, I only get the capturedArg as hello and not hello anirudh. How can I get hello anirudh instead?

Why do you need object? Your spy is identical to B spyB = spy(B.class); There is no A in your class and I don't think Mockito allows you to intercept/capture super calls.

What do you get when checking captor.getAllValues()?
